# Replace в регулярном выражении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Не могу разобраться в replace в регулярном выражении.
Вот сама регулярка:
`/(^https?:\/\/www\.dropbox\.com)(\/s\/\w+\/[\wа-яА-Яё]+\.\w+)/`
Применяться будет к такого рода ссылкам:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f15pra2dssf7zvwf7b/333.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhdkdf15dykctjdp004/376.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx70sj1gru4vsawhg9/517.jpg?dl=0
```

Вообще задача состоит в том, чтобы заменить, к примеру, первую ссылку, на такую:
`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2f15pra2dssf7zvwf7b/333.jpg`

То есть нужно заменить первую часть ссылки и убрать ненужный мусор типа `?dl=0`.

Вот сама функция `.replace`:

```
var1.replace(/(^https?:\/\/www\.dropbox\.com)(\/s\/\w+\/[\wа-яА-Яё]+\.\w+)/,
"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/$2")
```

Пример на regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ErgOTW/3

То есть по сути мне не понятно, почему `.replace` просто не заменяет совпадение конкретно в первой группе и не выводит всё остальное, а заменяет прям всё найденное совпадение. Не знаю как этого избежать.
Посоветуйте решение, пожалуйста.

Comment: _почему .replace просто не заменяет совпадение конкретно в первой группе и не выводит всё остальное, а заменяет прям всё найденное совпадение._ - можешь подробнее расписать? не совсем понятно. что имеется ввиду

Comment: Чтобы убрать `лишний мусор` в конце регулярки нужно добавить `.*`

Comment: @vp_arth, это не верно. Зайди на сайт  https://regex101.com и предложи этот вариант, дописав в конце `.*`. И не дай бог она не будет убирать этот мусор в конце или в регулярке будет хоть один лишний символ кроме этих двух, точки и звездочки. Зачем ты пишешь чушь?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ErgOTW/4 Вам бы над тоном поработать...

Comment: @Grundy, ну подробнее написано выше, где описывается то, что я хотел бы получить от регулярки. Но она этого не делает, делает не то, что я бы хотел... Это и есть подробнее ведь.

Comment: @vp_arth, прошу прощение за напор) Действительно работает. Но почему, не можешь рассказать? Как этот `.replace`, что он отсеил эту также захваченную в поиск часть? Ведь по сути всё выражение попадает под поиск.

Comment: В ответе ниже всё вроде описано. Нужно захватывать всё, что планируется менять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вашей регулярки в том, что она *не захватывает* часть после знака `?`. Как следствие, [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) применяется только к основной части URL.

Правильная регулярка может иметь вид:

```
var re = /(^https?:\/\/www\.dropbox\.com)(\/s\/\w+\/[\wа-яё]+\.\w+)\?.*/mgi;

[
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f15pra2dssf7zvwf7b/333.jpg?dl=0',
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhdkdf15dykctjdp004/376.jpg?dl=0',
  'https://www.dropbox.com/s/kx70sj1gru4vsawhg9/517.jpg?dl=0'
].forEach(function(str) {
    console.log(str.replace(re, 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com$2'));
});
```

Вот рабочий [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfbx67ne/3/). А вот и [пример на regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pGDZUv/3) для иллюстрации работы самого регулярного выражения.

Comment: Спасибо, такой же вариант был раньше предложен в комментариях. А скажите, лучше регулярку не написать? Или это вполне "презентабельный" вариант?

Comment: Я бы выкинул `[а-яё]` и сделал последний блок (`\?.*`) опциональным. В остальном, если речь идет о разборе именно ссылок (а не выкусывании их из текста) регулярка вполне сносная.

Comment: Ну и заодно можно привязаться к началу и концу строки.

Comment: Ну к началу ведь привязана регулярка посредством `^`, не? А конец после расширения файла нужно просто обрезать, так что конец не представляет никакой ценности. Кстати, в функции `.replace` в тексте  `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/$2` следует убрать самый последний слеш. На сайте регулярок я этот косяк исправил (и у тебя его также нет), но как-то всплыл в jsfiddle - в ссылке дублируется слеш, ссылка не рабочей получается, но это просто для перфекционизма)

Comment: @VostokSisters, Исправил